# Balls and their cardinality

Tags: metric-spaces

Let metric space $X$ and fixed point $a\in X$ be given.
I search for  not restrictive assumption under what all balls in metric space $X$ with center in $a$ have the cardinality equal the carinality of $X$.

Comment: Define not restrictive.

Comment: I know for example that this property have balls in normed  spaces. It is too much restrictive.